How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-r\cos 2p}{1-2r\cos 2p+r^2}(\tan p)^adp$?
In our midterm exam of Complex Analysis, we're asked to evaluate
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-r\cos 2p}{1-2r\cos 2p+r^2}(\tan p)^adp.
$$
We are allowed to use any method, like Residue Theorem.
I have no idea how to deal with it. I could find the left part is $\mathrm{Re}\dfrac{1}{1-re^{2pi}}$, but what to do next? It seems always cumbersome when choosing whatever contour.
Thanks in advance!

Hint : use the Poisson Kernel expansion $\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos 2p+r^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} r^{|n|} e^{inp}$

@JeanMarie I'm sorry but what to do next? I can't easilt calculate the integral inside involving $(\tan p)^a$...

What is $a$ ? An integer, a positive number, bounded ? Same question for $r$

We denote the integral in the question by $I(a,r)$. First, through replacing $p\to\pi/2-p$, it is easily observed that $I(-a,-r)=I(a,r)$. For this reason, WLOG we will assume $a\ge 0$. Second, we know that $\lim_{p\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-} (\frac{\pi}{2}-p)\tan p=1$. For this reason, $I(a,r)=\infty$ when $a\ge 1$. Hence, we assume $0\le a<1$. Third, $I(a,r)$ is continuous over $(a,r)\in (-1,1)\times \Bbb R$.

Lemma 1:
For any $a\in[0,1)$, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{\frac{s_k}{t_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$, converging to $a$, such that $1\le s_k<t_k$ $s_k+t_k$ is an odd number.


Proof: Consider $s_k=2\lfloor10^ka\rfloor$ and $t_k=2\cdot 10^k+1$ $\blacksquare$

Using the continuity of $I(a,r)$ over $(-1,1)\times \Bbb R$, we achieve
$$
I(a,r)=\lim_{k\to\infty}I\left(\frac{s_k}{t_k},r\right).
$$
By substituting $y=(\tan p)^\frac{1}{t}$ we have $dp=\frac{ty^{t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy$. Therefore
$$
I\left(\frac{s}{t},r\right){
=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-r\cos 2p}{1-2r\cos 2p+r^2}(\tan p)^\frac{s}{t}dp
\\=
\int_0^\infty\frac{1+r-2r\cos^2p}{(1+r)^2-4r\cos^2p}y^s\frac{ty^{t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy
\\=
\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+r)(1+\tan^2p)-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+\tan^2p)-4r}y^s\frac{ty^{t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy
\\=
t\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+r)(1+y^{2t})-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+y^{2t})-4r}\frac{y^{s+t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy
\\=
\frac{t}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(1+r)(1+y^{2t})-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+y^{2t})-4r}\frac{y^{s+t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy,
}
$$
where we have used Lemma 1 for the last equality. From this point, the famous semi-circle contour does the rest of the job. We have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(1+r)(1+y^{2t})-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+y^{2t})-4r}\frac{y^{s+t-1}}{1+y^{2t}}dy
{
=
\oint_C\frac{(1+r)(1+z^{2t})-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+z^{2t})-4r}\frac{z^{s+t-1}}{1+z^{2t}}dz.
}
$$
This equality is true, since the integral over the section $z=Re^{i\phi}$ for $0<\phi<\pi$ vanishes, due to the greater degree of denominator than numerator, by application of Lemma 1. Sparing the details, we have
$$
\oint_C\frac{(1+r)(1+z^{2t})-2r}{(1+r)^2(1+z^{2t})-4r}\frac{z^{s+t-1}}{1+z^{2t}}dz
=
\frac{\pi\left(2-\left|\frac{1-r}{1+r}\right|^\frac{s}{t}\right)}{2t\cos\frac{\pi s}{2t}}
$$
therefore
$$
I\left(\frac{s}{t},r\right)=
\frac{\pi\left(2-\left|\frac{1-r}{1+r}\right|^\frac{s}{t}\right)}{4\cos\frac{\pi s}{2t}}
$$
and
$$
I(a,r)=
\frac{\pi\left(2-\left|\frac{1-r}{1+r}\right|^a\right)}{4\cos\frac{\pi}{2}a}
$$
$
\blacksquare
$
